# Check for null value in LINQ before performing operation on it

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010

I am using the SharePoint 2010 REST services to extract information from an SP list. One of the conditions is that if a date exists in a record, and the year of that date is this year, then include it. Otherwise, don't.

What I'm concerned about is that I have to use a date cast method on the date field, and if that field is null then the code will fail. Is there any way to check if the value is null BEFORE using the cast?

My current code is here:

```
    Dim results As List(Of CurrentProjectsItem) =
        (From items In service.CurrentProjects
         Where (items.StatusValue = "Closed" Or CDate(items.DateClosed).Year = Now.Year))
         Order By items.Priority
         Select items).ToList()
```

Any help would be appreciated, I don't use LINQ all that often!

Answer (score 0):

You can include that check in your condition.  So this:

```
CDate(items.DateClosed).Year = Now.Year
```

logically becomes this:

```
((items.DateClosed Is Not Nothing) And (CDate(items.DateClosed).Year = Now.Year))
```

(Though I'm curious what *type* `DateClosed` is in the first place, if not a `Date`?)

**Edit:**

> The DateClosed is Date?

In that case it's a `Nullable(Of Date)` object, which has properties on it for checking this:

```
((items.DateClosed.HasValue) And (items.DateClosed.Value.Year = Now.Year))
```

No need for casting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply David, and the solution which I'll try out. The DateClosed is Date?, and I may have jumped the gun a little there. I didn't realise that the properties for it were DateClosed.Value.Year, I was trying DateClosed.Year which obviously didn't work!

Comment: @Mark: Ah, a `Date?` is certainly a usable type for this.  I've updated the answer accordingly.